# Craft Commerce - Bad Request The CSRF token could not be verified

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I've been following the Craft Commerce tutorials at Mijingo, (running on CraftPro 2.6.2983) all good so far, except when I go add a product to my cart. I'm getting a "CSRF token could not be found" error.

The debug message with dev mode on reads:

> Warning: Declaration of Craft\UserSessionService::login($username, $password, $rememberMe = false) should be compatible with CWebUser::login($identity, $duration = 0) in /Users/username/projectname/craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Declaration of Craft\UserSessionService::afterLogin() should be compatible with CWebUser::afterLogin($fromCookie) in /Users/username/projectname/craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php on line 17

Is there a step or setup option I'm missing? Atm, it's running on Mamp, but I want to make sure it's workable before I license up and go live.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!  Would you mind adding your edit as an official answer in case someone else runs into it in the future?

Answer (score 4):

My bad - sorted it out by adding {{ getCsrfInput() }} - as per https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection